# From callback url, how do I get the last req and res after callback?

Tags: node.js, express

User accesses to `/search` url then I authenticate user.

Once it's logged in, it redirects to /login/callback.

Then I want to redirect the user to `www.myproxy/search`.

Currently, it's redirecting to `www.myproxy/login/callback`. I can't find any way to get the previous `res` and `req`.

How do I get the previous `res` and `req` after the callback?

```
app.get('/login',
    function (req, res, next) {
        console.log('-----------------------------');
        console.log('/Start login callback ');
        next();
    },
    passport.authenticate('samlStrategy'),
);

app.post('/login/callback',
    function (req, res, next) {
        console.log('-----------------------------');
        console.log('/Start login callback ');
        next();
    },
    passport.authenticate('samlStrategy'),
    function (req, res) {
        console.log('-----------------------------');
        console.log('login call back dumps');
        console.log(req.user);
        console.log('-----------------------------');
        apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: serviceProvider})
    }
);
app.all('*',
  function (req, res, next) {
      console.log('-----------------------------');
      console.log('/Start login callback ');
      next();
  },
  passport.authenticate('samlStrategy'),
  function(req, res) {
    console.log('passing source!')
    apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: serviceProvider})
  }
);
```

Comment: Also, seems like a way to "bind" the existing function... How do I do that?

Comment: It should be a way to bypass the passport if it has the `token`. Not sure how it works in node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay the thing is http is a stateless protocol, so what I mean by stateless is
you cannot know what happened in earlier request and response, and can neither keep a track of future req and resp, it has to be done explicitly somewhere in your app(only if you want to track the reqs and resps).

But here in your case I suggest you to add an additional parameter to your req body with a redirect route and if it is null or default, set a default route, and add the route to your response url.

Comment: Could you elaborate with more with some examples?? I'm still struggling.

Comment: Maybe I can pass the previous URL in req. But I'm not sure how I can do that

Comment: i think this article might be of some help   https://verticalaxisbd.com/blog/redirection-to-requested-url-after-login-in-nodejs/

Comment: I made a progress. Could you follow up this question? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58022506/create-proxy-server-according-to-the-specific-url